# Are Google Apps Script Library quotas measured against the owner or active user?

Tags: google-apps-script

If you publish a [Google Apps Script Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) are the [script quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) applied per library owner or for the library user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries are not web services. It goes exactly like when you are using client side lib like Jquery.
When you are using an Apps Script lib, you just add extra code to the one in your code editor. So quota is measured against the lib user.
Otherwise it would be impossible to have libs used by many many users :)

Best,
Romain