# If a Google Apps Script Web App is being run by another user, does it consume the user's quota or the owner's quota?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I am new to Google Apps Script and programming in general. I am actively reading Stack Overflow questions and official documentation as well. For question number 2 below, I couldn't find any information, at least one which I could understand.

I have read about [App Scripts Quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and have few doubts regarding that. My apologies if it is a duplicate question.

Question/Doubts:

Let's say I have a script and I deploy it as a web app, while setting `Execute the App as` to `User accessing the web app`.

1. Now that while I ran the script myself it was consuming my Quota, whose Quota will it consume when another user runs the app as himself/herself?

   Reading [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) and [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733831/are-google-apps-script-library-quotas-measured-against-the-owner-or-active-user) I think it's his/her quota that will be used.

   Am I correct?
2. If my script is using <strike>Advance Google Services</strike> Standard GCP Project, I manually enable APIs in developer console.

   What happens when an user runs my script (deployed as web app) and he/she didn't enable API?

Edit: Question 3 removed as it deviates from the topic.

I hope my questions aren't too broad instead of being specific and adhere to Stack Overflow rules. I will really appreciate any information that clears my doubt.

Comment: You should post each question separately

Comment: @Rubén Removed Question 3. I think 1 and 2 are related. Is it okay to keep those two?

Comment: 1. Yes 2.  I'm not sure, but Why don't you test  and see? You don't *manually enable APIs in developer console* for *default* projects.

Comment: @TheMaster Sorry. I got confused between Advanced services and standard GCP Project. Corrected it now.

Comment: The short answer is that it will come off of the users quota. If they don't enable the APIs they'll get an error and they will have to enable them.

Comment: @Cooper You should add it as a answer